# How to encrypt a value imported from a JSON file using SOPS (Secrets OPerationS) and Go?

Tags: security, go, mozilla-sops

I have a JSON file as follows.

secret.json:

```
{
    "secret": "strongPassword"
}
```

I want to print out an encrypted value of the key "secret".

I've so far tried as follows.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "go.mozilla.org/sops"
)

type secretValue struct {
    Value string `json:"secret"`
}

func main() {
    file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("secret.json")
    getSecretValue := secretValue{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &getSecretValue)
    encryptedValue, err := sops.Tree.Encrypt([]byte(getSecretValue.Value), file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(encryptedValue)
}
```

As you might have guessed, I'm pretty new to Go and the code above doesn't work.

How can I improve the code to print out the encrypted value?

Please note that I'm writing code like this only to see how SOPS works using Go. I don't print out secret value like this in production.

**Edit:**

I think the problem is the arguments for the Encrypt function. According to the documentation, it should take []byte key and Cipher arguments, but I don't know either if I'm setting the []byte key correct or where that Cipher comes from. Is it from crypto/cipher package?

**Edit 2:**

Thank you @HolaYang for the great answer.
I tried to make your answer work with the external JSON file as follows, but it gave me an error message saying `cannot use fileContent (type secretValue) as type []byte in argument to (&"go.mozilla.org/sops/stores/json".Store literal).LoadPlainFile`.

```
 package main

import (
    hey "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"

    "go.mozilla.org/sops"
    "go.mozilla.org/sops/aes"
    "go.mozilla.org/sops/stores/json"
)

type secretValue struct {
    Value string `json:"secret"`
}

func main() {
    //  fileContent := []byte(`{
    //    "secret": "strongPassword"
    //    }`)
    file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("secret.json")
    fileContent := secretValue{}
    //_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &fileContent)
    _ = hey.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &fileContent)
    encryptKey := []byte("0123456789012345") // length 16

    branches, _ := (&json.Store{}).LoadPlainFile(fileContent)
    tree := sops.Tree{Branches: branches}
    r, err := tree.Encrypt(encryptKey, aes.NewCipher())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Comment: `key` is an argument for `Cipher.Encrypt`, and Cipher is an interface, maybe you can see my code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the function declaration of `sops.Tree.Encrypt` *(a typo here in your code)*.
By the code, we should do in these steps.

1. Construct a `sops.Tree` instance with the json file.
2. Use a certain `Cipher` for your encrypt.

Try yourself in this way please.

Code demo below, with AES as Cipher, and sops can only encrypt the total tree with the source code interface.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "go.mozilla.org/sops"
    "go.mozilla.org/sops/aes"
    "go.mozilla.org/sops/stores/json"
)

func main() {
    /*
    fileContent := []byte(`{
    "secret": "strongPassword"
    }`)
    */
    fileContent, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("xxx.json")

    encryptKey := []byte("0123456789012345") // length 16

    branches, _ := (&json.Store{}).LoadPlainFile(fileContent)
    tree := sops.Tree{Branches: branches}
    r, err := tree.Encrypt(encryptKey, aes.NewCipher())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the typo, I edited my post. I would be really grateful if you could provide a complete code example based on the code I posted.

Comment: Thank you, that printed out an encrypted value. Your answer definitely helps a lot. One last question though, I was trying to adjust your code so that I could print out an encrypted value imported from an external json file. But I still can't get it working. I edited my post so that you can see what I want to do.